# Unable to create instance with local SSD on GCE

Tags: ssd, google-compute-engine

I try to create an instance with a local attached SSD on GCE.
I used the command from the docs:

```
gcloud compute instances create foobz \
     --machine-type n1-standard-8 \
     --zone us-central1-f \
     --local-ssd interface=nvme \
     --local-ssd interface=nvme \
     --image nvme-backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20141108 \
     --image-project gce-nvme
```

result:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Invalid value for field 'resource.diskTypes': 'projects/xxx/zones/us-central1-f/diskTypes/local-ssd'.  Resource was not found.
```

My `gcloud` is up to date

```
gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.64

alpha 2015.06.02
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
compute 2015.06.09
core 2015.06.09
core-nix 2015.06.02
dns 2015.06.02
gcloud 2015.06.09
gcutil 1.16.5
gcutil-msg 2015.06.09
gsutil 4.13
gsutil-nix 4.12
kubectl
kubectl-darwin-x86_64 0.18.1
preview 2015.06.09
sql 2015.06.09
```

I run OSX.
Did I forget something?

Comment: What did Google support say about this?

Comment: The command is good. If you run it from a GCE linux machine it will work. I'll try to test it on a OS X computer tomorrow.

Comment: @EEAA well... the support is pointing to servervault or Google Groups

Comment: I tested the command on Mac OS X and it worked. did you try this command from a GCE VM instance to make sure the issue is not related to your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My account was a trial account. It seems SSDs are only available for full accounts.